# KeyError: <tkinter.Button object .!button>

Tags: python, button, tkinter

When trying to run this code, I get a key error that says

```
KeyError: <tkinter.Button object .!button4>
```

The button number is different for all the buttons 1-5.

I dont understand what it is implying as I thought I was referring to the right button. Please help! Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def button_click(event = None):
    which_button = event.widget
    var = f[which_button]

    if var in f:
        var.set(f[var])
    else:
        for i, j in enumerate(v):
            if j == v[i]:
                var.set(k[i])

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Flashcards")
k=[]
v=[]

f={"Bonjour": "Hello",
   "Lundi": "Monday",
   "Parler": "To Talk",
   "Manger": "To Eat",
   "Dormir": "To Sleep"}

for key,val in f.items():
    k.append(key)
    v.append(val)

for i in range(5):
    s = tk.StringVar()
    s.set(k[i])

    b = tk.Button(window, textvariable = s, width = 10)
    b.bind("<Button-1>", button_click)
    b.grid(row = 0, column = i)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined what `which_button` is, and what `f` is? Clearly, `which_button` is not a member of `f`.

Comment: No, the buttons are instances of `tk.Button`. `"Bonjour"`, `"Lundi"`, etc. are strings, not buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but: Why use bind when Button has a callback function? With `partial()` you can give each button a specific callback.

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

def button_click(event=None, key=None):
    print(key, '-', f[key])

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Flashcards")

f={"Bonjour":"Hello","Lundi":"Monday","Parler":"To Talk",
   "Manger":"To Eat","Dormir":"To Sleep"}
for i,key in enumerate(f.keys()):
    b = tk.Button(window, text=key, width = 10)
    b.bind("<Button-1>", partial(button_click, key=key))
    b.grid(row = 0, column = i)

window.mainloop()
```

If you are unfamiliar with `partial`, it's similar to `lambda:` but with different syntax.